# Bad Input Shape

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I don't know that my code is correct or not. but I got the error:

> bad input shape (1, 301)

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd

clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Armin\\Desktop\\heart.csv')
x = [df.age[1:302], df.sex[1:302], df.cp[1:302], df.trestbps[1:302], df.chol[1:302], df.fbs[1:302], df.restecg[1:302], df.thalach[1:302], df.exang[1:302], df.oldpeak[1:302], df.slope[1:302], df.ca[1:302], df.thal[1:302]]
y = [df.target[1:302]]

clf.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use fit function. but the error doesn't let me. Can you check my code? it mayble wrong. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add also the csv file you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sure. https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci

Comment: I don't have access to the file (it needs some kind of subscription). The idea is that you edit the question yourself (by pressing the _edit_ link on the bottom left corner) and add this info, since people need it to be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: You can access easily. The site is free for all.

Comment: Armin, the goal is to have complete questions with all he information needed to understand and reproduce the problem in one single place (it's called a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Without all the needed information, your question is not likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple fix.

You need all the columns from `df` in `x` except the `target` column, for that, just do:

```
x = df.drop('target', axis=1)
```

And your `target` column will be:

```
y = df['target']
```

And now do your `fit`:

```
clf.fit(x, y)
```

It will work.

---

**PS:** What you were trying to do is passing `list` of `Series` having the features value. But what you just need to do is, pass the actual values of your feature set and targets from the dataframe directly.

Some more references for you to get started and keep going:

- Read more about what to pass to the `fit` method here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit
- Here is a super basic tutorial from the folks of scikit themselves: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html